# Visual Basics Me keyword not existing in current context

Tags: vb.net

Hello I am new to Visual Basics and am trying to make a exit buttom to close my form. I have the button made but inside the method it will not let me use Me.close(), does anyone know where I am going wrong?

[image: Visual Studios Screenshot]

Comment: First thing ... learn what language you are using.  Second thing ... if you want help, post your code not just a picture of your code.

Comment: `Me` == `this`... Also this is a simple debugging issue which is off topic.

Comment: You named your c# project VBTutorial1?

Comment: @LarsTech comment of the year!

Comment: lol, that's c#.

Comment: Essential reading: [ask], the [tour] and [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) (not *Basics*).  Also read the usage guidance text on the tags - they will tell you that vba is not VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

Your project is in C#, not VB.NET.

If you want to keep using C# (I'd recommend that), use the `this` keyword.